# Multiple polygon arrays with the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I'm following the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays) for creating Polygon Arrays with the Google Maps API. I want to create multiple polygons that each have a different name when you click on them. In the code below, I want the first triangle to be called "name 1" when you click it and the second triangle to be called "name 2" when you click it. I attempted to do this, but they are both called "name 2" when you click on them. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polygon Arrays</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.
// When the user clicks on the polygon an info window opens, showing
// information about the polygon's coordinates.

var map;
var infoWindow;
var name;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var bermudaTriangle;

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
  var triangleCoords = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
      new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
      new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  name = 'name 1';

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', showArrays);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var triangleCoords = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(40.774252, -95.190262),
      new google.maps.LatLng(33.466465, -81.118292),
      new google.maps.LatLng(47.321384, -79.75737)
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  name = 'name 2';

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', showArrays);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

/** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
function showArrays(event) {

  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath()
  // to return the MVCArray of LatLngs.
  var vertices = this.getPath();

  var contentString = '<b>' + name + '</b><br>' +
      'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
      '<br>';

  // Iterate over the vertices.
  for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
    var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
    contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
        xy.lng();
  }

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

You're basically having issues with [variable scope](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/), and I'm going to emphasize two problems I'm seeing.

First, you're declaring the `name` variable at the top of your application, and you're setting its value twice. The second time, when it's set to "name 2", it's overwriting the initial value of "name 1". This is exactly what you're doing..

```
var name;
name = "name 1";
name = "name 2"; // this second assignment overwrote the assignment above it
```

I hope it make sense seeing it like that.

Second, you're also overwriting the `bermudaTriangle` variable in the exact same way, only the nature of your application isn't causing you to see any bugs as a result of this mistake.

**And <s>the</s> a Solution**

If I fix the Javascript portion of your code and make some additional improvements, it looks like what follows ([here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0ydpbe5/) to see it in action). Some points of note:

1) Because I think it's cleaner, I moved the `paths` and the `map` properties inside the JS statements initializing your two polygons.

2) I changed `name` from being an application-level variable, which you were instantiating and then overwriting, into an optional property belonging directly the polygon objects themselves, and I set that value within the polygon declarations.

> For clarity I wanted to keep the same property name you originally used. Although, to avoid unintended collisions with undocumented properties, it's *better practice* to give any dynamic/custom properties you create a unique prefix and use that same prefix across your application. With that in mind, `name` should probably be something more like `x_name`, etc.

3) I gave your second polygon the unique variable name, `otherTriangle`.

```
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.466465, -81.118292),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    // These are declared outside of the init function, so I
    // initialized them together at the top of the function..
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    // Here's where your data begines. I moved the 1) API-supported paths object, 
    // 2) the API-supported map object, *AND* 3) the dynamic name value inside 
    // the Polygon object declarations.. this makes "name" a property of the object.
    var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
        new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
        new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)],
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        name: 'name 1', // dynamic, not an official API property..
        map: map
    });

    // Here's the behavior handler..
    google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', showArrays);


    // This is a new, different object therefore we should instantiate it relative
    // to a new variable (i.e. a unique pointer). Once again I moved the paths, map,
    // and name properties inside the object declaration.
    var otherTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.774252, -95.190262),
        new google.maps.LatLng(33.466465, -81.118292),
        new google.maps.LatLng(47.321384, -79.75737)],
        strokeColor: '#008700',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#008700',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        name: 'name 2', // dynamic, not an official API property..
        map: map
    });

    // Aaaaand, the behavior..
    google.maps.event.addListener(otherTriangle, 'click', showArrays);

}

// The only differnece here is that I changed "name" to this.name,
// becuase "this" (the object that fired the event), now carries around 
// that "name" property we gave it..
function showArrays(event) {
    var vertices = this.getPath();

    var contentString = '<b>' + this.name + '</b><br>' +
        'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
        '<br>';

    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
        var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
        contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' + xy.lng();
    }

    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

    infoWindow.open(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm completely new to JavaScript so this helps a lot.